# url id is accidentally replaced with favicon in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been working on a rails project (rails 5.2.4) for a while. Most of the things work great. But I sometimes meet an issue that the `id` included in url is accidentally replaced with the string of `favicon`.

For example, here I typed in `http://myproject.com/objects/153`. The log show

```
I, [2020-10-22T20:45:17.394223 #14]  INFO -- : Processing by ObjectController#show as 
I, [2020-10-22T20:45:17.394289 #14]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"favicon"}
I, [2020-10-22T20:45:17.401109 #14]  INFO -- :   Rendered object/show.html.erb within layouts/application (3.5ms)
I, [2020-10-22T20:45:17.401247 #14]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

The reason the code, in the end, shows 500 is there is a before action to get the record by using `Object.find()`. But apparently, as `id` has been replaced by `favicon`, the desired record cannot be found.

But if I typed in another url like `http://myproject.com/objects/151`, it works well. In the log, you can see

```
I, [2020-10-22T20:45:17.394223 #14]  INFO -- : Processing by ObjectController#show as 
I, [2020-10-22T20:45:17.394289 #14]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"151"}
I, [2020-10-22T20:45:17.401109 #14]  INFO -- :   Object Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "objects".* FROM "objects" WHERE "objects"."id" = ? ORDER BY "objects"."name" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 151], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

The routes.rb is configured as

```
resources :objects, only: [:new, :create, :show, :edit, :index, :update, :destroy ]
```

So I have no idea why the same code works for one case but can't work with another. And I have no idea how to debug. As the very first line of the code is `@object = Object.find(params[:id])`.

For further details, please see app/views/layouts/application.html.erb attached below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <% app = respond_to?(:app_name) ? app_name : "Define helper method 'app_name'"%>
    <title>
      <%= app %>
    </title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
      <%= split_stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
    <![endif]-->
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= google_analytics %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag %>
  </head>
  <body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>" style="background-color: #f6f6f6; margin-bottom: 50px;">
    <% content_style = "" %>
    <% if @redirect_to_if_iframe %>
      <% content_style = "display:none" %>
    <% end %>
    <div id="maincontent" style="<%= content_style %>">
      <% if @redirect_to_if_iframe %>
        <%= javascript_tag("redirect_if_iframe('#{@redirect_to_if_iframe}', 'maincontent');") %>
      <% end %>
      <div id="headerbar" style="display:block; position: fixed; top:0; width: 100%; z-index: 9999999;">
        <%= javascript_tag("handlePortal('headerbar');") %>   <!-- found in datacommon.js -->
        <header>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default myproject-nav" role="navigation" style="height: 71px !important;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                  <%= image_tag "https://cloud.data-static.myproject.com/resources/images/current/logos/myproject-white.png", :align=>'middle', :alt=>"MyProject logo"%>
                </div>
              </div>
              <%if action_name != 'welcome' %>
                <div class="app_name_text", style="color: white; float: left;">
                  <%= app %>
                </div>
                <%= render :partial=>'layouts/myproject/userinfo' %>
              <%end%>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
      <%if action_name != 'welcome' %>
        <%= render :partial=>"layouts/myproject/navbar" %>
      <%end%>
      <div class="loading-container" style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <!--      <div class="loading-container">-->
        <div class="loading">
          <div class="icon">
            <%= image_tag "loading.gif" %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='container-fluid yield'
             style="background-color: white;
                    height: max-content;
                    width: 95%;
                    margin-top: 150px;
                    position: relative;
                    border-radius: 5px;">
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <%= send_tracking_data %>
</html>
```

Update:
While I do find a root cause for this issue, but I still can't explain why the actual id is replaced by `favicon` string. The root cause is the html for the corresponding view page may crush due to some formatting issue for the model if the user enters some invalid input. This kind of input is not invalid for the model, but invalid for html code to display. So the page is rendering `500`. But I should see the log that indicates the id is the actual one, then an error happens at a certain line in the view page. But it shows the `{"id"=>"favicon"}` first, which I still can't explain.

Comment: Please share your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file. I'm looking for what is in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: @MikeGorski I have added the file.

Comment: Do you see a request with the actual ID before that one with `favicon` in the logs?

Comment: @arieljuod No, I didn't see the request with the actual ID before it is with `favicon`.

Comment: The browser tries to fetch a favicon, proably the error page has no favicon meta tag and it's trying to fetch the current's path + `favicon.ico` triggering that request, that matches the object's show route.

Comment: @arieljuod that somehow makes sense to me. In the development environment, I can see the actual id first in the log, and then the default error page is rendered. In the production version, while I didn't see the actual id in the log, as you explained, the error page is trying to find favicon, so I see the id becomes `favicon` string. But why the production log doesn't show up the actual id first?

Comment: You probably have a different log level in production https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels